# Apache HTTP Server offline installation

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, redhat, httpd.conf

Is is possible to use Apache web server with out installing latest rpm for Apache HTTPD using `rpm Uvh httpd<version>.<arch>.rpm` or `yum install httpd` , like we can do for tomcat on Linux machines?  Because i don't have root access to run  `rpm` or `yum`

We can achieve this for tomcat just by copy the tomcat directory toany desired location and run startup.sh , it would start the server running on default port 8080 and could be accessed using hostname:/8080.

But when I looked for such ready to use dump on Apache site i didn't find it for  Linux.

However for windows i have such feature available on apachelounge.com... Is   offline installation of Apache HTTP Server possible on Linux?

**On windows we can download the binaries from**  http://www.apachelounge.com/download/

[image]

and  just run the executable **httpd.exe** which would get the work done in couple of minutes.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the Apache project stopped making generic LInux binaries available a very long time ago. Alternatives: [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) or [compile it yourself](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/apache.html).

Comment: You mean  Build it with “make” command and sudo make install i dont have root access for that.

Comment: Yes - but you can replace the standard installation executed by `make install` by something more appropriate for your situation, obviously. You can even run apache out of your homedirectory if you desire to do so (not saying that that would be the best idea ever, just saying it can be done).

Comment: Can we copy an existing installation from other machine and run init.d/apache2 after changing the config?

Comment: If all dependencies are installed on the target computer and the Linux version of both servers is sufficiently equal that should work, but I think installing xampp will be easier,

Comment: Okay , Linux is same version. Let me try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91983/discussion-between-e-hashmi-and-fvu).

Comment: You have build it via GCC make